# Поддерживают ли компоненты NuxtJs передачу параметров?

Tags: nuxt.js

Можно ли в компоненты NuxtJs передавать какие-либо параметры? К примеру, создаю компонент для вывода кнопки - мне нужно как минимум задать текст, которыйй будет выводиться на этой кнопке - значит, в компонент нужно этот текст передать параметром.

Answer (score 0):

Передавать параметры между компонентами и родителями можно с помощью `props` и `emit`

Также есть `Provide / inject` - [обзор](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/component-provide-inject.html#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)

Также при необходимости можно использовать `pinia` или `vuex`, для глобального хранения, например, состояния и изменять его уже там, где ты захочешь.

Тестируйте и используйте то, что подходит под ваши задачи)

Удачи!)

[Пропсы](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow)

[Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/)